# Creating a conditional input field component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm creating a re-usable component for input fields where I can define them easier in one component tag with props. However, I want to make it versatile as to be able to use it as text, date, password, number etc. By a conditional prop. But I'm having trouble getting that prop to bind

Here is my input field component

```
<template>
<div class="uk-margin">
    <label class="uk-form-label" for="trackid">{{label}}</label>
    <div class="uk-form-controls">
      <input v-if="number" class="uk-input" type="number" v-model="defaultvalue" />
      <input v-else-if="date" class="uk-input" type="date" v-model="defaultvalue" />
      <input v-else-if="email" class="uk-input" type="email" v-model="defaultvalue" />
      <input v-else-if="password" class="uk-input" type="password" v-model="defaultvalue" />
      <input v-else class="uk-input" type="text" v-model="defaultvalue" />
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "input-text-field",
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String
    },
    defaultvalue: {
      type: String
    },
    type: {
      type: String
    },
    number: {
      type: Number
    },
    date: {
      type: Object
    },
    email: {
      type: String
    },
    password: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: ""
    };
  }
};

</script>
```

And I'm calling like this or would like to use them like this

```
<InputField label="User Name" :defaultvalue="myName" />
<InputField label="User Email" email :defaultvalue="myEmail" />
<InputField label="User Password" password :defaultvalue="myPass" />
<InputField label="Tracking #" number :defaultvalue="trackingNumber" />
```

In my understanding of this, if I call password, it should obfuscate the value as it would render the type="password" given the conditional statement. No? What am I doing wrong

*P.S. the defaultvalue would be stored and used as a state. That part works. Right now, I am not getting console errors, but the component renders as a text regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take this as an example:

```html
<VInputField label="User Password" password :defaultvalue="'myPass'"/>
```

After checking the console, we can see that passing `password`(when its prop type is `String`) is not enough.

```js
props: {
 /* ... */
 password: {
   type: String
  }
},

created () {
 console.log(this.$props);
 /*
  ...
  password: ""
  ...
 */
}
```

An empty string("", '') evaluates to false.

I can think of one approach, by making the prop's type `Boolean`:

```js
password: {
   type: Boolean
}
```

- `<VInputField label="User Password" :password="true" :defaultvalue="'myPass'"/>`

[Here is a CodeSanbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-p0f5i).

### Edit

By passing password this way
`<VInputField label="User Password" password :defaultvalue="'myPass'"/>`
you will always get a **true** value(if the prop's type is also Boolean).

Answer (score 2):

`v-else-if="password"` tests the value of the `password` prop. It is equivalent to:

```
if (vm.password)
```

However,

```
<InputField label="User Password" password :defaultvalue="myPass" />
```

provides the `password` prop, but without a value which is the same as `:password="true"`. However, the password prop requires a string, not a boolean. In that case, Vue apparently assigns the empty string to the prop which evaluates to `false`. It's the same with all your other examples which is why the `else` clause is always chosen.

By the way, you should have warnings in the console regarding this. You shouldn't ignore those.

This should work:

```
<InputField label="User Password" password="true" :defaultvalue="myPass" />
```

However, I suggest you rework your component. Instead of having so many props defined, have a single one called `inputType` and pass the desired input type as a string. Then you would have:

```
<InputField label="User Email" inputType="email" :defaultvalue="myEmail" />
<InputField label="User Password" inputType="password" :defaultvalue="myPass" />
```

Comment: I agree on the idea of simply passing in the input type instead of making a conditional component, seems a bit messy.

I've made a fiddle of how I'd build the custom input component
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-7m29w